# UDP connection do not receive any reply from server - Python (potentially also c++ using boost)

Tags: python, c++, sockets

I am trying to establish a connection to a server, and send some data to it.. 
The problem is that, if i try to debug the connection using this MICHAEL SIEGENTHALER | TCP/UDP Debugging Tools 
which clearly shows that there is no issue with the communication, and even some form of random input will result in a data coming out.

but when i try to code it in python, using the same settings, are no response received.. It stalls after it has sent the message, i am not sure whether whether it has send the message, or skipped it?

It seems like my server aren't receiving the message i sent to it, and therefore don't reply.. but what is different?

```
import socket   #for sockets
import sys  #for exit

# create dgram udp socket
try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
except socket.error:
    print ('Failed to create socket')
    sys.exit()

host = 'localhost';
port = 5634;

while(1) :
    try :
        #Set the whole string
        s.sendto(("-1-117230").encode('utf-8'),('10.2.140.183', 9008))
        print("sent")

        # receive data from client (data, addr)
        d = s.recvfrom(1024)
        reply = d[0]
        addr = d[1]

        print ('Server reply : ' + reply)

    except socket.error as msg:
        print ('Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1])
        sys.exit()
```

[image]

what is different from the code, and the way the debugging tool test it?

I tried to code it in c++ using boost, but as i had the same issue, i went on to trying in python to see whether that would make a bit more sense.

---Updated --

```
import socket   #for sockets
import sys  #for exit

# create dgram udp socket
try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    server_adress = ('10.2.140.183',5634)
    s.bind(server_adress)
except socket.error:
    print ('Failed to create socket')
    sys.exit()


while(1) :
    try :
        #Set the whole string
        s.sendto(("-1-117230").encode('utf-8'),('10.2.140.183', 9008))
        print("sent")

        # receive data from client (data, addr)
        d = s.recvfrom(1024)
        reply = d[0]
        addr = d[1]

        print ('Server reply : ' + reply)

    except socket.error as msg:
        print ('Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1])
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: Among other things, if the sent datagram is lost, your code just waits forever.

Comment: Can you give us the code as text and not as a picture, noone will type it all just to try it out

Comment: Added the code as text, and yes you are right about it being lost.. but the issue here is that i can't connect to it, so adding that would only make re sending, and yeah do the same thing..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the [binding](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/socket.html#socket.socket.bind) method.

This is kind of an echo server:

```
import socket
import sys

host = ''  
port = 8888
buffersize = 1
server_address = (host, port) 
socket_UDP = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP) 

socket_UDP.bind(server_address)

while True:
    data, from_address = socket_UDP.recvfrom(buffersize)
    if data:
        socket_UDP.sendto(bytes("b"*buffersize, "utf-8"), from_address)
socket_UDP.close()
```

Comment: is it possible using python to retrieve the client_adress instead explicitly stating it?

Comment: Soo... just to be certain..
you bind the UDP socket to the server address. 
And wait for an response from that same address??

The problem (i think) here is that the client has to be able to send to ('10.2.140.183', 9008)  = (ip,port) , but the server respond using another port 5634, which i why the client i my case is listening to that port.. so the client has to listen to another port, rather the same it sends to..

Comment: The code above is like an echo server. And you need to bind the server address. Of course, you can switch `recvfrom` and `sendto`, if you want to act like a client...

Comment: So the only change i have to perform is this...
-- please look at updated code --
this result in exception being caught, and print failed to create socket.

Comment: I assume this is because there is already a socket running on this port on this machine.

Comment: Not being the case.. 
 `s.bind(server_adress)
OSError: [Errno 49] Can't assign requested address`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96663/discussion-between-michael-dorner-and-lamda).